# How to add mediaplayerelements controls in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

How do you enable basic button controls on your `MediaPlayerElement` like <kbd>play</kbd>, <kbd>pause</kbd> or advanced features like <kbd>Fast Forward</kbd> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MediaPlayerElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement) already have all the basic controls to **Pause/Play**, **Stop**, **FastForward** etc. you just need to set the **AreTransportControlsEnabled = true** and you will have all the basic controls on your mediaplayerelement.

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayer"
          Source="ms-appx:///Media/video1.mp4"
          AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" />
```

and to enable **FastForward** like buttons on it you can explicitly enabled them on your [MediaTransportControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediatransportcontrols) like this :

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaElement1" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/audio.wma"
          AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">
    <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
        <MediaTransportControls IsZoomButtonVisible="False"
                                IsFastForwardButtonVisible="True"
                                IsPlaybackRateButtonVisible="True" IsPlaybackRateEnabled="True"/>
    </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
</MediaPlayerElement>
```

> you can notice apart from fastforward button there are many other buttons to enable advanced features as well like playbackrate button and zoombutton.

Comment: please attach a screenshot